# how to check if the second array key is an array?

Tags: php

i have an array which could look like this:

```
 $config[$name][$array]['key'] = 'value'; // here it's an array
```

or

```
 $config[$name][$array] = 'value'; // here it's not an array
```

i want to check if the second array key ('array') is an array or not.

could someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the function `is_array` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

```
if(is_array($config[$name][$array])) echo "Yup I'm an array";
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a built in function, [`is_array`](http://php.net/is_array). That should let you know whether or not you have an array, or a plain string.